# Empty list of attributes to change on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to submit a grid form like the below one,

[image]

**show.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for :datadef, url: update_all_vmodule_path do  |fdf|%>
      <table  id="csvfiles" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="10%">Column No</th>
            <th width="20%">Column name</th>
            <th width="20%">Data type</th>              
            <th width="15%">Column format</th>
            <th width="10%">Length</th>
            <th width="25%">Comments</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>            
          <% @datadefrecords.each do |ddre| %>
            <%= fields_for "datadef_records[]", ddre do |dr_fld|  %>
            <tr>                
              <td><%=  ddre.column_no %></td>
              <td><%=  ddre.column_name %></td>
              <td><%=  dr_fld.collection_select :column_datatype, Datadef.select(:column_datatype).uniq, :column_datatype, :column_datatype, {:prompt => true} %> </td>
              <td><%=  dr_fld.text_field :column_format %></td>
              <td><%=  dr_fld.text_field :column_length %></td>
              <td><%=  dr_fld.text_field :comments %></td>
            </tr>   
            <% end %>
          <% end %>                 
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>                    
              <td colspan="2"><%= fdf.submit 'Save' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to("<button>Cancel</button>".html_safe,  cancelmodal_vmodule_path ) %></td>
            </tr>                                
        </tbody>
      </table>        
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This the method i am calling it to submit

```
  def update_all
     session[:datadef] = nil    
     @updatedatadef = Datadef.all.where(:id => params[:datadef_records]).update_all(update_all_params)    
     redirect_to migproject_path(params[:vmodule][:migproject_id])
  end
```

This is the strong parameters

```
  def update_all_params
     params.require(:datadef_records).permit( :column_datatype, :column_format, :column_length, :comments)
  end
```

This is how i get the parameters from form

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"QrX8JYYYQOlfwKgAABJd0+A7VpugS2Y6n8doDsuKqeM=",
 "datadef_records"=>{"12"=>{"column_datatype"=>"varchar",
 "column_format"=>"2",
 "column_length"=>"2",
 "comments"=>"2"},
 "13"=>{"column_datatype"=>"varchar",
 "column_format"=>"2",
 "column_length"=>"2",
 "comments"=>"2"}},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

But i get this "Empty list of attributes to change" error which is not allowing me to write it in table. And i am not able to identify what could be the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the output of `update_all_params`

Comment: In table there 2 records with id of (12,13) on these records.   <br/>

"column_datatype"=>"varchar",
 "column_format"=>"2",
 "column_length"=>"2",
 "comments"=>"2"   <br/>

these data should be written.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is to do with your use of `update_all`, although I'm not 100% sure as to the syntax of the problem.

From what I understand, `update_all` needs a hash of actual params to populate your data; even then, it will only update what you pass to it (kind of like [`update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes)).

[Here's a good reference](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-rails-activerecord/):

```
data = params[:datadef_records]
@updatedatadef = Datadef.update(data.keys, data.values)
```

This negates the use of your `strong_params`, which I'd recommend using. I'd have to spend some time thinking about getting it to work.